# Why $\beta=\{a+r: a\in \alpha\}\neq \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a Dedekind cut?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $\alpha$ be a Dedekind cut and $r\in \mathbb Q^+$. I'd like to show there is $a\in \alpha$ such that $a+r\in \mathbb Q\setminus \alpha$.

**Proof.** Define the subset

$$\beta=\{a+r: a\in \alpha\}\subseteq \mathbb Q.$$

It is not hard to show that $\beta$ is a Dedekind cut and $\alpha\subseteq \beta$. It is left to show $\alpha\neq \beta$. In fact, if $\alpha\neq \beta$, there exists $a\in \alpha$ such that $a+r\in \beta\setminus \alpha$. In particular, $a+r\in \mathbb Q\setminus \alpha$.

So, my question is: how to show $\alpha\neq \beta$.

*Remark:* A *Dedekind cut* is a subset $\alpha\subseteq \mathbb Q$ such that:

DC1) $\alpha\neq \phi$ and $\alpha\neq \mathbb Q$;

DC2) If $q\in \alpha$ and $p\in \mathbb Q$ are such that $p<q$, then $p\in \alpha$;

DC2) If $q\in \alpha$ there is $p\in \alpha$ such that $q<p$.

Comment: You should clarify your definition of Dedekind cut. I am guessing: a nonempty downward-closed subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with no maximum element?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: ... and which is not equal to all of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha = \beta$ then for all $a \in \alpha$ we have $a + r \in \alpha$.

Additionally, $\alpha$ contains a closed interval $[x,x+r] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ for some $x$ (because $\alpha$ is nonempty and downwards-closed).

Then $\alpha$ also contains $[x+r, x+2r] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, and then $[x+2r, x+3r] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, etc.

Thus $\alpha$ contains $\{a \in \mathbb{Q} : a \geq x\}$.

But also $\alpha$ is downwards closed!

So $\alpha = \mathbb{Q}$. This contradicts the assumption that $\alpha$ is  Dedekind cut.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

If $\beta = \alpha$, then for every $a\in \alpha$, $a+r$ is also in $\alpha$. Thus $a+r+r=a+2r$ must also be an element of $\alpha$. Proceeding similarly, $a+nr$ must be an element of $\alpha$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

But, if $b\in \mathbb{Q}-\alpha$, then, one can find a positive integer $n$ such that $a+nr > b$ (Aechimedian principle). This clear contradicts that $\alpha$ is a Dedekind cut.